# How to write crash-robust code?

Tags: export, kernel, crash, save, memoization

When a notebook crashes all the work I was doing is lost - I'd like to ameliorate this situation!

Is there a way to decorate a symbol so that it is saved to disk whenever it changes, or after a certain repeating time interval?

I find myself wasting lots of time manually performing such a disk-caching mechanisms for important variables and functions (usually by appending to global lists and saving new .mx files with `DumpSave` by hand). Here's what I'd like to call it:

```
CrashProtect[_Symbol] := (* ... *)
CrashProtect[_Function] := (* ... *)
```

I realize there is overhead involved but typically only a few symbols or functions are critical and would need this sort of treatment.

Note: MMA 10.3 kernel is more stable than ever! Sadly the front-end crashes for me still very frequently - especially when dealing with dynamics or large/multiple notebooks.

Comment: You have Mma 10.3?

Comment: $Post comes to mind.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291299/590388), see especially the "File-backed In-memory Approach" section.

Comment: You might want to check out `LocalSymbol` and `LocalObject`.

Comment: Also `PersistentValue`, if you have 11.2. Allows you to save persistently in a `Notebook`.

Comment: I don’t really understand the difference between local and persistent symbols

Comment: It would be so nice if there once will be a Mathematica (notebook) version which does not crash. I am used to it by now, after nearly 25 years of using Mathematia notebooks. I understand it is hard to achieve, but that would be really valuable:  a more robust Wolfram Mathematica notebook frontend ( and no, the cloud frontend has other trouble and cannot replace the standalone frontend ).

Answer (score 3):

#### If you can keep a cell on screen, Dynamic can do it.

Perhaps not the prettiest of methods, but here's one possible approach:

```
autobackup[x_, f_] := Dynamic[Put[x, f]; "Magic cell - used for backup.", 
    UpdateInterval -> 30, Initialization :> (x = Get[f];)];
```

Takes a variable `x` and file path `f`, and creates a `Dynamic` cell that automatically saves the value of `x` to disk at `f` whenever `x` changes (specifically, when those changes trigger `Dynamic` cells) or every 30 seconds. It then reloads those values from the disk whenever the `Dynamic` cells are initialized, providing continuity across kernel sessions.

Will not work with functions specified in the standard `SetDelayed` (`:=`) syntax, but should work with functions specified as `f=Function[{x},x+...]`, which may be useful in some projects.

This does require keeping the magic cell around though, since that's what the `Dynamic` is attached to, and thus the output should not be suppressed with `;`.

Reloading the values after a kernel crash/quit may require re-running the `autoupdate` input cells.

#### Otherwise, you can schedule a repeating task to save at a constant time interval.

```
autobackup[x_, f_, t_] := (If[FileExistsQ[f], x = Get[f]]; 
    RunScheduledTask[Put[ReleaseHold[x], f], t]);
SetAttributes[autobackup, HoldFirst];
```

This takes a variable `x`, file path `f`, and time between saves `t`, and creates a scheduled task which will attempt to save `x` to `f` every `t` seconds.

#### If you want dynamic updating without the magic cells, you can attach the Dynamic to the notebook.

```
autobackup[xl_List, f_] :=
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookDynamicExpression ->
    Dynamic[
        If[nbdeinit === True, Put[Evaluate[xl], f], 
            If[FileExistsQ[f], xl = Get[f]];
            nbdeinit = True],
        TrackedSymbols :> xl]];
SetAttributes[autobackup, HoldFirst];
```

This takes a list of variables `xl` and a file name `f`, and sets up a `NotebookDynamicExpression` which will update so long as the notebook is open. This does require the use of a dummy initalization variable, because apparently the `Initialization` rule for `Dynamic` won't trigger for `NotebookDynamicExpression`. Also note that this doesn't appear to recover gracefully from kernel crashes unless the notebook is reopened, though it won't break anything either (the `Dynamic` is simply not evaluated at all, it seems).

Comment: This will work only while the `Dynamic` cell is displayed on the screen...

Comment: Is that so? That can be somewhat mitigated by having it in a separate notebook on another screen, rendered; but that becomes very convoluted quickly. I'll take a look at alternatives.

Comment: @eyorble This looks like a wonderful idea. How  can this modified so that at a timed interval the entire contents of `EvaluationNotebook[] ` (the notebook being worked on) is dumped into another file (i.e. `mynotebookBACKUP.nb`) completely replacing everything in there if not empty without affecting the focus of the directory structure when doing a manual `File->Save` of `mynoteook.nb`? I could see using something like this on half hour intervals while using manual saves more frequently when working on risky code.

Comment: @JulesManson Seems like a different fundamental question to me, but you can `Export[filename,EvaluationNotebook[]]` to save the current notebook. Combining that with the second code in my answer above in place of the `Put[...]` would likely work for your needs. You likely want to include a timestamp in the filename so that you can rollback to any version you need to in the event of a crash. `.nb` files aren't usually extremely big, so disk space probably isn't an issue. Like normal saves though, won't save any additional variable states though.